# Codeigniter set_value() foreach loop

Tags: php, codeigniter

I generate a form, which mostly consists of input fields that are already populated with values from the db.

So I do this currently like so:

```
<input id="misc" name="misc" value="<?php echo $workout['misc']; ?>" />
```

But when I try and do this:

```
<input id="misc" name="misc" value="<?php echo set_value($workout['misc']); ?>" />
```

along with a validation rule, the form does reload itself, the error message does display **BUT the form is reset**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be just `echo set_value('misc')`? Would be helpful to see how the form is defined/displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As per the manual:**

Permits you to set the value of an input form or textarea. 
You must supply the field name via the first parameter of the function. 
The second (optional) parameter allows you to set a default value for the form. 
Example:

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo set_value('quantity', '0'); ?>" size="50" />
```

The above form will show "0" when loaded for the first time.

**Hence in your case:**

```
<input id="misc" name="misc" value="<?php echo set_value('misc', $workout['misc']); ?>" />
```

**OR**

```
<input id="misc" name="misc" value="<?php echo set_value('misc'); ?>" />
```

**Documentation:**

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html